# php GD imagecopy large image too slow

Tags: php, image, performance

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);

$dest = imagecreatetruecolor( 16*416, 16*208);

for($x=0;$x<13;$x++){

    for($y=0;$y<7;$y++){

        $src= imagecreatefromjpeg( "https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?

cb_client=maps_sv.tactile&authuser=0&hl=en&panoid=mrDfhatcSqCCmarHrRdk1A

 &output=tile&x=".$x."&y=".$y."&zoom=4");

        imagecopy($dest , $src, $x*512, $y*512, 0, 0, 16*416, 16*208);

        imagedestroy($src);

    }

}
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
```

My memory limit is 128M, image size is 4M,I could not change it, but it should be ok,
This loop take 20s to run, only one image.

I feel imagecopy is slow in the loop,Can I improve this code or do it on another way?

UPDATE

never use PHP GD2 for larger and massive images, imageMagick is much more faster

Comment: Please format the source code correctly, it is hard to read. Is it possible that the retrieval from the internet address takes that long and not the actual processing? Have you tried this with a local image (file)?

Comment: sorry about format :(   I am new here. I have edited format,I will try local image, but take time, I need dowload 28 images